# Equal kinetic energy in two bodies of different masses

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

Two bodies that are equal in their size rest in a table. There isn't friction between the bodies and the table.

The mass of one of the bodies $(A)$ are $4$ times bigger than the mass of the second body $(B)$.

$$m_A = 4m_B$$

The bodies are pulled by a force $\vec{F}$ in a straight line until they reach to a specific end line.

Why is the kinetic energy of both bodies equal at the end of the end line? I thought it would be bigger the kinetic energy of the body $A$ because of
$$E_{k_a} = \frac 124mv^2$$
$$E_{k_b} = \frac 12mv^2$$
And then
$$E_{k_a} \gt E_{k_b}$$

What are my misunderstandings?

Comment: I read it and don't understand why it says they have equal kinetic energy.

Comment: hint: use the [work-energy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#General_derivation_of_the_work.E2.80.93energy_theorem_for_a_particle): the change in kinetic energy of either body is $\Delta E_k=W$, where $W$ is the work done by the force.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Oh...  right! You can put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! How about the other way around? you found the solution to your own question: post it here as an anwer so it may be useful for future readers, and I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming both start at the same starting line and cross the same finishing line then the amount of *work* done on the two objects is identical and equal to:

$$F\Delta x,$$

where $\Delta x$ is the distance between the two lines, aka the *displacement*.

Since as acc. the work-energy theorem this work has been converted to kinetic energy, then:

$$F\Delta x=E_{ka}=E_{kb}$$

Where you went wrong is that you assumed both would reach the same speed $v$ but that's not the case:

$$v_a=\sqrt{\frac{2F\Delta x}{m_A}}$$

$$v_b=\sqrt{\frac{2F\Delta x}{m_B}}=\sqrt{\frac{8F\Delta x}{m_A}}=2v_a$$